# Replicating overfit_batches functionality of Pytorch lightning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

The Pytorch lightning has `overfit_batches` option for it's trainer. but I have created a custom dataloader with a custom sampler. when the trainer with `overfit_batches=True` is run, I see that it tries to change my sampler. my sampler plays an important role on how my custom dataloader behaves. so it's gives error because the sampler of my dataloader has got changed.

- side question: why Pytorch lightning changes the sampler of dataloader? same thing happens for finding best learning rate.

### question:

so I want to keep my dataloader as it is, with my custom sampler, but instead of `overfit_batches=True` use `limit_train_batches=1` but I don't know is there a possibility of using different batches when having `limit_train_batches=1`?ofc assuming that I have turned off the shuffle of dataloader.

`general question`: with what configs or lines of code I can use to replicate `overfit_batches` without using it's original option `overfit_batches=True`